# Binding NSTableView and NSArrayController together

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, controller, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I have an app controlled by a big controller. In my principal window, I have a button, which when pressed I want to open a new window where data would be stored into an `NSTableView`.

After reading some documentation, I found something very interesting and useful between `NSTableView` and `NSArrayController`.

So I would like to know if it's possible to display data in an `NSTableView` controlled by a `NSArrayController` from an `NSMutableArray` edited in my Controller.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this is what `NSArrayController` is for. See [Creating a Master-Detail Interface](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Tasks/masterdetail.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002090-BCICADHC) in *Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics* for full instructions on how to wire this up. You'll probably also want to look at [Providing Controller Content](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/CntrlContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002147-BCICADHC) if you're not already familiar with that part.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i have an another question now a bit different, i want to display in one of this array's row an url which will open a web page when you'll click on it . How can you do that pleasee?

Comment: That's a completely different subject; you should open a new question for it so that others can search in the future.